# @AuthenticationPrincipal not up to date after permission change

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I have a controller which is called by an ajax call when a button is pressed in a modal dialog.

```
@PostMapping(path = "/{year}/{week}/{scheduleId}/publish/ajax")
@PreAuthorize(MA_CMA_CHEF_PUBLISH_CONDITION)
public String publishSchedule(Model model, @PathVariable Long locationId, 
    @PathVariable Integer year, 
    @PathVariable Integer week, 
    @PathVariable Long scheduleId, 
    @RequestBody SchedulePostInfo scheduleInfo, 
    @AuthenticationPrincipal ApplicationUser appUser) {
    return super.publishSchedule(model, scheduleId, scheduleInfo, appUser);
}
```

I am trying to test that the authorization works, and do the following:

Make sure the user has the necessary permissions.

Open the modal dialog, and do not click the publish button immediately.

Then, in the permissions tool, as an admin in a separate browser, remove the publish permission and save in order to pull the permission from the user.

Now, in the modal dialog, press "publish".

This works without any error(but it should not) and debug output show the "publish" permission is still set in the application user context (created from the principal).

My first question is, is this due to the principal not being up to date?

My second question is, can it be fixed?

Comment: The `UserDetails` is not up to date with the changes. When the user authenticates, the `UserDetails` is saved in the session by default and is not changed until they authenticate again. One option would be to use Spring Session and invalidate that user session after you change the permission. You could also save the authorities in a session attribute and retrieve them from there.

Comment: Or, you can configure a custom `AuthorizationManager` that instead looks up the authorities at request time from the admin server. The authorization manager can decide how often to check the admin server for updated permissions. OAuth is another common way to address distributed authorization issues like these.